# Why is direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep deprecated?

Tags: grep

According to the manual page of [grep-Programs](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/grep-Programs.html#grep-Programs),

> In addition, two variant programs egrep and fgrep are available. egrep is the same as ‘grep -E’. fgrep is the same as ‘grep -F’.
>
> Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.

Why are they deprecated?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They have been [removed from POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap04.html), with the following [rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html):

> This *grep* has been enhanced in an upwards-compatible way to provide the exact functionality of the historical *egrep* and *fgrep* commands as well. It was the clear intention of the standard developers to consolidate the three *grep*s into a single command.
>
> The old *egrep* and *fgrep* commands are likely to be supported for many years to come as implementation extensions, allowing historical applications to operate unmodified.

So `egrep` and `fgrep` are basically temporary artifacts on the way to a complete `grep`, which has now been available for a long time; they have served their purpose and are no longer needed, hence their deprecation.

Further evidence for this is to be found in old Unix releases: `egrep` and `fgrep` didn’t have separate manpages, they were documented in the [`grep` manpage](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/man/man1/grep.1), which states explicitly

> Ideally there should be only one *grep*,
> but we don't know a single algorithm that spans a wide enough
> range of space-time tradeoffs.