# zgrep vs. egrep vs. grep

Tags: grep

Is there an easy-to-remember rule of thumb to know what is the difference between:

- `egrep`
- `zgrep`
- `grep`

and to know which ones are installed in my machine?

(Indeed it seems that there is some:  "if GNU grep is installed, then ..., else ...")

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`zgrep` is generally a script shipped with `gzip` (see also Stephen Kitt's comment below) that `grep`s into compressed files (with compression formats that `gzip` recognises). The `z` is for **z**ip (not for the pkzip compressed archive format, but for the zipping/compression of files).

`egrep` was a command introduced in Unix V7 in the late 70s with a new regexp algorithm and syntax compared to the old `grep` (itself a standalone command to implement the `g/re/p` command of the ancient `ed` text editor). That's the `grep` for the **e**xtended regexps (ERE), as opposed to the *basic regexps* (BRE) understood by `grep`/`sed`/`ed`/`vi`.

Additional operators like `\{` and `\<` were later added to some implementations of `grep` but not `egrep` making `grep` on some aspects more *extended* than `egrep`.

In the early 90s, POSIX tried to unify `egrep` and `grep` into a single command (where `grep -E` is meant to do what `egrep` did) and make the `{min,max}` operator in ERE equivalent to `\{min,max\}` in `grep`'s REs (so not backward compatible with `egrep`). It also specified the `-F` option for ***f**ixed string* search to replace the `fgrep` utility.

Today, `egrep` is not a standard command (neither is `fgrep`). While most systems have one, some implementations recognise the `{min,max}` operator, some don't.

`grep` and `grep -E` are standard. Some `grep` implementations have extra switches to recognise even more different regexp syntaxes like `grep -P` for PCRE (or `perl`-like, see also the `pcregrep` command shipped with the PCRE library), `grep -X` for *augmented* regexps...

And the list of operators supported by `grep` and `grep -E` varies from one system to another. For portability, restrict to the list specified by POSIX.

On Solaris, make sure to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`. The one in `/bin` is not POSIX compliant.

Various compression libraries/tools provide with `zgrep`, `bzgrep`, `xzgrep` scripts, none of which standard.

The only compression program that POSIX specifies is [`compress`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/compress.html)/[`uncompress`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/uncompress.html) which  is for an ancient compression format from the early 80s that nobody uses anymore.

`gzip` (GNU `zip`) understands another ancient compression format that is still in use nowadays and `gzip` is found on most systems (either the GNU implementation or a clone). So you should be able to do:

```
gzip -d < file.gz | grep BRE
```

or:

```
gzip -d < file.gz | grep -E ERE
```

to `grep` into gzip-compressed files. You can do the same with any other compression format provided you have access to the corresponding tool.

Comment: There's also `fgrep`, that could perhaps stand for _flat_ `grep`.

Comment: @SatōKatsura, yes, good point, I'll add a note for that.

Comment: Some distributions ship [Zutils’ `zgrep`](http://www.nongnu.org/zutils/zutils.html) instead of the `gzip` script. It supports more formats than `gzip`; it will handle uncompressed files and files compressed with `gzip`, `bzip2`, `lzip` or `xz`.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer with historical details. Could you a note for noobs like me like: if you don't know what to use, take grep or grep -E , it will likely be present in your distribution  (is it true or did I misinterpreted your answer?). PS: I mostly use standard Debian and Ubuntu on another computer.

Comment: @Basj, on GNU systems like Debian and derivatives, `grep`, `egrep`, `fgrep` will all be GNU `grep` and be mostly POSIX compliant (more compliant if you set the `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable) with many extensions, and `fgrep` will be exactly like `grep -F` and `egrep` exactly like `grep -E`.

Comment: See also [Why is direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383448/86440) for some more historical background.