# Exact number of same characters in word-grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, wildcards

My task is to find lines with egrep in which first word contains **exactly** three same letters.
I've tried to use backreferences but only found a way to build pattern which finds words builded from 3 or more same characters:

```
egrep -i '^[^[:alpha:]]*\<[a-z]*([a-z])[a-z]*(\1[a-z]*){2}\>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following matches any "word"  at the beginning of a line consisting of only 3 of the same [:alpha:] character:

```
grep -i '^\([[:alpha:]]\)\1\1\b'
```

Or, with grep's `-E` (`--extended-regexp`) or `-P` (aka `--perl-regexp`) options:

```
grep -iE '^([[:alpha:]])\1\1\b'

grep -iP '^([[:alpha:]])\1\1\b'
```

These work with GNU grep and (except for the `-P` version) with FreeBSD's grep.  They may not work with other versions of grep.

---

If you want to match words of any length containing **3 or more** of the same alpha character anywhere within them, it's a bit more difficult.  You need to use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which requires perl compatible regular expressions.

i.e. it cannot be done with `grep -E` (aka `egrep`, which has been [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383448/why-is-direct-invocation-as-either-egrep-or-fgrep-deprecated)).

For example:

```
$ grep -iP '^[[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]])((?:(?!\1)[[:alpha:]])*\1){2}[[:alpha:]]*\b' /usr/share/dict/words
Aaliyah
Aaliyah's
Aarau
Aargau
Aaronical
Abadan
Abbottstown
Abbottstown's
Aberdeen
Aberdeen's
...
zoozoo
zoozoos
zuzzes
zwitterionic
zygogeneses
zygomorphous
zymogeneses
zyzzyva
zyzzyvas
zzz
```

(according to `wc -l`, this matches 67117 out of the 344817 words in my /usr/share/dict/words file)

---

And, finally, to match only words with **exactly 3** of the same [:alpha:] character anywhere within them:

```
$ grep -iP '^[[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]])((?:(?!\1)[[:alpha:]])*\1){2}[[:alpha:]]*\b' /usr/share/dict/words | 
  grep -viP '^[[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]])((?:(?!\1)[[:alpha:]])*\1){3}'
```

The first grep finds words with 3 or more of the same character, and the second excludes those with 4 or more.

I'm not sure if this can be done with a single regex or not.

(this matches 56820 words in my /usr/share/dict/words file).

Comment: Your 2nd version will match `tattooists` (4 a's and 4 t's, but no letter 3 times) but not `zoologist` (3 s's). Backreferences are NOT the way to go about it.

Comment: huh? there's only 1 a in tattooist.  and 4 ts. the 2nd version matches 3 or more, as mentioned.  zoologist is a problem, i'll look into that.

Comment: BTW, back-references with negative lookaheads **are** the way to do it.  In fact, that is the **ONLY** way to do it with a single regular expression alone.

Comment: messed the letters a bit when copy-pasted, sorry: so 4 t's in `tattooists`, no letter exactly 3 times as required in the OP.

Comment: can you not read?  2nd version is explicitly documented as "If you want to match words of any length containing **3 or more** of the same alpha character anywhere within them".   3 or more encompasses 4.

Comment: Could it be done with regexps + backreferences at all? that's an interesting question.

Comment: @UncleBilly it seems that it can.  and it also seems that you need to know that back-references and look-aheads (or look-arounds in general) are not the same thing.   Related, in that they're both part of regular expressions (as are character classes and quantifiers), but not the same.

Comment: Still not there: recklessness, underdeveloped, assassination, inconvenience, transcontinental, maintainability, etc.

Comment: you still can't read.  the 2nd version (without the `grep -viP`) will match 3 or more of the same alpha char.  as has been mentioned multiple times.     The version **with** `grep -viP`  excludes any 4-or-more matches.

Comment: `recklessness` has exactly 3 `e`s and your final code doesn't match it. Read you own "finally, to match only words with exactly 3 of the same ...". Do you need some code the check your regexps against?

Comment: `recklessness` also has 4 `s` chars in it, so it is excluded.   The OP hasn't specified how that conflict is to be resolved, or even if it IS a conflict, so I'm going with "can't have more than 3 of the same character".   If you have a different interpretation, feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: Then `banana` should be excluded too, because it has 3 `a`s, but only 2 `n`s. And `puppy` too, because it has only 1 `u` and 1 `y`.

Comment: 1 or 2 of any letter is irrelevant.  Stop trying so hard for faulty excuses to be pedantic, it's both undignified and demeaning.

Comment: 1. behave yourself 2. you're not fooling anyone

Comment: **I** am not attempting to fool anyone.   Go pester someone else with your false pedantry - you don't even have the excuse of being right.

Comment: Fails to match `gewürztraminer` (3 `r`'s) or `o'keeffe` (with 3 `e`'s). I am not sure why ....

Comment: Should `tastelessness teleconferencing teletypewriter teletypewriters tempestuousness timelessness tintinnabulation tintinnabulations tirelessness transcontinental transgressors transubstantiation` (just to list a few) be rejected? All have exactly 3 of one character while also having 4 of some other character.

Comment: @Isaac gewürztraminer may be due to locale or unicode issues.  o'keeffe definitely because the embedded `'` triggers `\b`.   The other words you listed - as already mentioned more than 3 of same character = exclude, even if there's exactly 3 of another.

Comment: Allowing apostrophes is easy enough. I decided against it because that would match on the possessive form of all words with 2 `s` characters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to do that with `grep` and regular expressions, even with perl/pcre features like zero-length assertions and backreferences.

This is most probably some theoretical rabbit hole, but I'm out of my depth with such stuff.

So just do it in perl. The "algorithm" could be easily translated to awk, ruby, python, etc:

```
perl -CiI -anle 'my ($i,%l); ($n=++$l{$_})==3 ? $i++ : $n==4 ? $i-- : () for $F[0]=~/\pL/g; print if $i' file
```

This could be easily adapted. For instance, if you want to find words which have 3 letters repeated 3 times:

```
perl -CiI -anle 'my ($i,%l); ($n=++$l{$_})==3 ? $i++ : $n==4 ? $i-- : () for $F[0]=~/\pL/g; print if $i >= 3' /usr/share/dict/words
...
entertainment
...
totalitarianism
```

or 7 letters repeated 2 times:

```
perl -CiI -anle 'my ($i,%l); ($n=++$l{$_})==2 ? $i++ : $n==3 ? $i-- : () for $F[0]=~/\pL/g; print if $i >= 7' /usr/share/dict/words
...
electroencephalograph
...
telecommunication
```

You can also change `\pL` to just `.` to match any letter, `$F[0]=~/../` to just `/../` and no `-a` switch to match the whole line, omit `-CiI` to only consider ascii letters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** way to build such regex with only ERE (extended regex).

The closer with GNU grep (perl regex) (which match 3 or more repeated characters) is:

```
grep -P '(\w)(((?!\1)\w)*\1){2}' filename
```

So, removing words with 4 or more repeats, you will get an answer:

```
grep -P      '(\w)(((?!\1)\w)*\1){2}' filename | 
    grep -Pv '(\w)(((?!\1)\w)*\1){3}'
```

An alternative with GNU awk is:

```
awk '{
      a=$1;
      while (length(a)){
                        b=gensub(substr(a,0,1),"","g",a);
                        if(length(a)-length(b)==3){print $0;next};
                        a=b
                       }
     }' filename
```

It works by removing all repeats of the first character, if the removal was of 3 characters then print it, else, remove the next first letter until there are no more characters to replace (an improvement is to test only if the remaining length is equal or bigger than the repeat required).

Assuming that you want to count `A` as equivalent to `a`, then filter your file with:

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words | tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]] > words
```

The two solutions are similar but not equal. The two differ on words like `independence` from the dictionary file generated above.

Yes, `independence` contains 3 `n`'s but 4 `e`'s. Depending of which is found first the word may be included or not. Awk solution is stable and will include words in which **any** character is repeated exactly 3 times. A regex solution is more slipery and will match in some conditions and not in others.

Additionally, the regex will match only *word* characters which do not include `'` (and the file contains several words with that character).

In all, the number of lines matched is (1527 more with awk):

```
 13758 awklist
 12231 greplist
```

And, removing the `'` (184 more with awk):

```
 9236 awklist2
 9052 greplist2
```

Should `tastelessness teleconferencing teletypewriter teletypewriters tempestuousness timelessness tintinnabulation tintinnabulations tirelessness transcontinental transgressors transubstantiation` (just to list a few) be rejected?

All do have exactly **3** of one character and four (or more) of another.

Comment: `\w` is more than just alpha (from perlre: `alphanumeric plus "_", plus other connector punctuation chars plus Unicode marks)` - which is why I didn't use it.

Comment: `grep -P ... | grep -Pv ...` will not be inconsistent, and the output will not depend on which letter is seen first - any word with more than 3 of the same character will be excluded.  Always.   Your awk and grep solutions implement different rules and *will* have different output, but they will both be self-consistent.    Also, using `\w`, your grep version will match words containing `'`.  Using `[:alpha:]`, it wouldn't.