# No response of egrep command on large folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, performance, macos

I need to get some files that doesn't contain some string on a large folder ≃ 10M files for 22 GO of data.

I try this command on local (macOS) :

```
egrep -r -L -Z 'string1|string2' * | wc -l
```

this work well (because to the number of files I got on local I think ≃ 500)
but on my server I get no output and I can't stop the execution with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.

So my question is:

> Is there a way to achieve this command on a large folder? Or, Is there another way to count the number of files that do not contains 'string1' **or** 'string2'?

Comment: It may have tripped upon a fifo; try with `egrep -Dskip -r ...`

Comment: @mosvy thanks to your reply, on local this work but same thing on server, when I try to execute the command in the directory I get this error : -bash: /bin/egrep: Argument list too long

Comment: Run with `.` instead of `*`.

Comment: @El-Burritos congratulations, you just hit ArgMax see http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Comment: @mosvy After some minutes I get a 0 result with `.`

Comment: Don't use the GNU grep `-r/-R` options to find files as it just creates Frankenstein calls to grep. Keep your code simple and robust and just use `find` to **find** files and `grep` to **g/re/p** within the files. There are big clues in the command names to their function!

Comment: Thanks for the tips @EdMorton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
find . -type f -exec egrep -r -L 'string1|string2' {} +  | wc -l
```

- `.` To search all from the current directory.
- `type f` To search only in files.
- `+` will use as many arguments per command to avoid **exceeding the maximum limit of arguments per line**

Comment: You don't need the `-r` and [`egrep` is deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383448/133219) in favor of `grep -E`.