# Is "egrep" part of the POSIX standard

Tags: grep, posix

The `egrep` command has been deprecated in favour of `grep -E`.

The [POSIX definition for `grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) includes the following note,

> This `grep` has been enhanced in an upwards-compatible way to provide the exact functionality of the historical `egrep` and `fgrep` commands as well. It was the clear intention of the standard developers to consolidate the three `grep`s into a single command.
>
> The old `egrep` and `fgrep` commands are likely to be supported for many years to come as implementation extensions, allowing historical applications to operate unmodified.

There is no POSIX command definition entry for `egrep` itself, however.

Does this section confirm that `egrep` is a recognised POSIX command (even if one that is deprecated), or does it merely note that the command used to exist and *should* be (as distinct from *must* be) supported for the foreseeable future?

Trying to put it another way, what is the situation of `egrep` with respect to POSIX?

Comment: They're clearly not part of the standard, since the second paragraph points out that they'll likely be provided--as implementation ***extensions***.

Comment: @ThomasDickey In https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap04.html it says _The following utilities were removed in the previous version of this standard_, and goes on to include `egrep`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I wasn't sure whether "_implementation extensions_" meant POSIX or not

Comment: It's clearly not part of the modern standards. I can't seem to find a copy of IEEE Std 1003.2-1992 (POSIX.2) online, which is the oldest and which might include it. Even LibGen only has 1003.1-2008.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383448/why-is-direct-invocation-as-either-egrep-or-fgrep-deprecated)

Comment: @forest it’s documented in pages 295-296 of POSIX-2:1993.

Comment: @muru that's a good link for a very closely related question. I don't think it quite answers my question, though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The “Utilities Removed in the Previous Version” section in the rationale part of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap04.html#tag_23_04_02) says that

> The following utilities were removed in the previous version of this standard:
>
> […] `egrep` `fgrep`

This means that `egrep` is no longer part of POSIX (including extensions). The consequences are at least that

- a system without `egrep` could be certified;
- a strictly POSIX-compliant utility must not expect `egrep` to be available.

There is no expectation of any kind that a POSIX system *should* include `egrep`, just a statement that it is possible that `egrep` is available for historical reasons.

I don’t know whether the certification test suite includes any conformity tests for `egrep` when it *is* present. In other words, I don’t know whether a system which includes an `egrep` command which isn’t equivalent to `grep -E` would fail conformance testing. (I imagine it wouldn’t, since `egrep` isn’t specified by POSIX.)